# rust vs c performance

Tags: c, performance, rust

I wanted to learn a bit about rust tasks, so I did a monte carlo computation
of PI. Now my puzzle is why the single-threaded C version is 4 times faster
than the 4-way threaded Rust version.  Clearly I am doing something wrong, or my mental performance model is way off.

Here's the C version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.1415926535897932

double monte_carlo_pi(int nparts)
{
    int i, in=0;
    double x, y;
    srand(getpid());

    for (i=0; i<nparts; i++) {
        x = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;

            if (x*x + y*y < 1.0) {
            in++;
        }
    }

    return in/(double)nparts * 4.0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nparts;
    double mc_pi;

    nparts = atoi(argv[1]);
    mc_pi = monte_carlo_pi(nparts);
    printf("computed: %f error: %f\n", mc_pi, mc_pi - PI);
}
```

The Rust version was not a line-by-line port:

```
use std::rand;
use std::rand::distributions::{IndependentSample,Range};

fn monte_carlo_pi(nparts: uint ) -> uint {
    let between = Range::new(0f64,1f64);
    let mut rng = rand::task_rng();
    let mut in_circle = 0u;
    for _ in range(0u, nparts) {
        let a = between.ind_sample(&mut rng);
    let b = between.ind_sample(&mut rng);

    if a*a + b*b <= 1.0 {
        in_circle += 1;
    }
    }
    in_circle
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    let ntasks = 4u;
    let nparts = 100000000u; /* I haven't learned how to parse cmnd line args yet!*/
    for _ in range(0u, ntasks) {
        let child_tx = tx.clone();
        spawn(proc() {
        child_tx.send(monte_carlo_pi(nparts/ntasks));
        });
    }

    let result = rx.recv() + rx.recv() + rx.recv() + rx.recv();

    println!("pi is {}", (result as f64)/(nparts as f64)*4.0);
}
```

Build and time the C version:

```
$ clang -O2 mc-pi.c -o mc-pi-c; time ./mc-pi-c 100000000
computed: 3.141700 error: 0.000108
./mc-pi-c 100000000  1.68s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.683 total
```

Build and time the Rust version:

```
$ rustc -v      
rustc 0.12.0-nightly (740905042 2014-09-29 23:52:21 +0000)
$ rustc --opt-level 2 --debuginfo 0 mc-pi.rs -o mc-pi-rust; time ./mc-pi-rust  
pi is 3.141327
./mc-pi-rust  2.40s user 24.56s system 352% cpu 7.654 tota
```

Comment: What does the profiler say? (ie: its a good lesson to learn to find the hotspots and bottlenecks in your code).

Comment: Don't compile with debugging symbols on.

Comment: `the single-threaded C version is 4 times slower than the 4-way threaded Rust version`. The numbers you posted seem to be the other way around

Comment: Cicada: I've fixed the question.

Comment: AndyG: I've updated the question: --debuginfo 0 had only a small impact on performance.  Still looking for the missing 4x

Comment: @RobLatham: You're also compiling the C version with the "-g" symbol, which you should take out.

Comment: Necrolis: what profiling tools exist in the rust ecosystem? In 2012, 'oprofile' was the answer: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2012-April/001558.html

Comment: @RobLatham The bottleneck here is probably the random number generator. Try `rand::XorShiftRng::new_unseeded()` instead of `rand::task_rng()` for a faster random generator.

Comment: @Dogbert: that is indeed much faster.  In this four task example, would each task generate the same random numbers if I used new_unseeded() ?

Comment: If you remove the threading in Rust what happens?

Comment: You can create a randomly seeded `XorShiftRng`, e.g. `let mut rng: XorShiftRng = rand::random();` (the speed improvement comes from the change in algorithm, not the lack of seeding).

Comment: now that's more like it.  On a 4 core system, four-way threaded rust is 4.5 times faster than the single-threaded C version. I'll accept Dogbert's answer if he wants to write it up, or I'll self-answer in a few days.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The bottleneck, as Dogbert observed, was the random number generator.  Here's one that is fast and seeded differently on each thread

```
fn monte_carlo_pi(id: u32, nparts: uint ) -> uint {
    ...
    let mut rng: XorShiftRng = SeedableRng::from_seed([id,id,id,id]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Meaningful benchmarks are a tricky thing, because you have all kinds of optimization options, etc. Also, the structure of the code can have a huge impact.

Comparing C and Rust is a little like comparing apples and oranges. We typically use compute-intensive algorithms like the one you dispicit above, but the real world can throw you a curve.

Having said that, in general, Rust can and does approach the peformance of C and C++, and most likey can do better on concurrency tasks in general.

Take a look at the benchmarks here:

https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/rust-clang.html

I chose the Rust vs. C Clang benchmark comparasion, because both rely on the underlying LLVM.

[image]

On the other hand, a comparasion with C gcc yields different results:

[image]

And guess what? Rust still comes out ahead!

I entreat you to explore the Benchmark Game site in more detail. There are some cases where C will edge out Rust in some instances.

In general, when you are creating a real-world solution, you want to do performance benchmarks for your specific cases. *Always do this, because you will often be surprised by the results.* Never assume.

I think that too many times, benchmarks are used to forward the "my language is better than your langage" style of rwars. But as one who have used over 20 computer languages throughout his longish career, I always say that it is a matter of the best tool for the job.